# c++ GetModuleHandle путь

Tags: c++, winapi

Скажите, в чем моя ошибка ?

```
HMODULE client = GetModuleHandle ("D:\mylib\file.dll");
```

Выдает 0(false). Информации, и простейшего примера работы этой функции не нашел.
P.S. Допустим, если ввести в аргумент lpModuleName значение kernel32.dll, то все хорошо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может сначала надо его загрузить с помощью [LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx), а потом выпрашивать у WinApi указатель на него?

Comment: Именно Ex ? или можно и LoadLibrary ?

Comment: Не важно, в Ex есть еще две дополнительные опции,

Comment: Нужно занести возвращаемое значение LoadLibraryEx в переменную и далее эту переменную указать в аргументе функции GetModuleHandle ? или же просто в функции LoadLibraryEx указать правильный путь до файла, а в GetModuleHandle указать имя файла.

Comment: И таки не забудьте удвоить бекслеши.

Comment: А как теперь мне значение LoadLibraryEx поместить в GetModuleHandle ?